# I can't remove an object from a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa, nsarray, nsarraycontroller

I don't understand why an object is not removed from an NSMutableArray. This is the code:

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"candidatesProxy"];
[candidatesProxy removeObject:[[pseudonymsArrayController selectedObjects] lastObject]];
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"candidatesProxy"];
```

I've checked and the lastObjet in pseudonyms is the same object of candidatesProxy. But it is not removed.

Is it because maybe the object has been copied to a different memory location, so I actually have 2 objects rather then one ?

Thanks

Comment: You have mentioned that lastObjet in pseudonyms is the same object of candidatesProxy. If the lastObject is element of candidatesProxy (instead of candidatesProxy itself), it will be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove objects from `NSArray`, you can remove it only from `NSMutableArray`

**EDIT**

Just try the following statements before `willChangeValueForKey:`

```
NSLog(@"Array : %@", candidatesProxy);
NSLog(@"Element : %@",[[pseudonymsArrayController selectedObjects] lastObject]);
```

and check whether the lastObject element is present in the array.

Answer (score 3):

When you use the `removeObject:` method on, the index of the object is first determined by sending `indexOfObject:` to that array, and then the object at that index is removed.

In order to make this working, ensure your custom object class override `-(BOOL)isEqual:`.

Alternatively, remove the object using an index, but you first need to determine it.